# Laravel 5.2 elasticsearch & easyautocomplete filtering

Tags: jquery, elasticsearch, laravel-5

I installed the elasticquent package to laravel. Search operations running smoothly. But I need to create a category based on the data type URLs.

Elasticquent package: https://github.com/mustafaaloko/elasticquent5

My search controller method:

```
public function search(Request $request){

        $key = $request->input('phrase');
        $companies      = $this->company->search($key);

        $projects       = $this->project->search($key);

        return \Response::json([
            'companies' => $companies,
            'projects'  => $projects

            ]);

    }
```

Easyautocomplete Javascript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {

        url: function(phrase) {
          return "{{ url('webapps/search') }}";
        },

        categories: [{
            listLocation: "projects",
            maxNumberOfElements: 5,
            header: "Projects"
        }, {
            listLocation: "companies",
            maxNumberOfElements: 5,
            header: "Companies"
        }],

        getValue: function(element) {
          return element.name;
        },

        ajaxSettings: {
          dataType: "json",
          method: "GET",
          data: {
            dataType: "json"
          }
        },

        preparePostData: function(data) {
          data.phrase = $(".search-input").val();
          return data;
        },

        requestDelay: 400,
        theme: "square"
      };

      $(".search-input").easyAutocomplete(options);

    });
```

My Search Results (Exmple)

https://codeshare.io/yKaSQ

How can I create the category link

Company url: http://localhost/companies/{id}
project url: http://localhost/projects/{id}

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom template for your results:

```
template: {
    type: "custom",
    method: function(value, item) {
        return "<a href='{{url('companies')}}/" + item.id+ "' >" + item.name+ " </a> "
    }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. But how do i create for multiple categories?

Comment: what do you mean by multiple?

Comment: Code which you send to me sets up all url types to "companies". But my result has more than one url type. How can i set link types as "companies / id" and "projects / id". Example: if(listLocation == 'projects'){
return 'project url';
}else{return 'company url';}

Comment: this will be a little trickier , you will need to alter your search results to return the type of result company or project